# Chrome does not play MP4

Tags: linux, google-chrome, video, gmail, mp4

I get several emails everyday to my Gmail account, from my security camera system. Such mail contains links to video clips (aprox 20 sec each) from cameras in MP4 format.
Strange is that on Mageia based PC after clicking on such link the clip is open and playback in new separate browser card. And it is correct situation for me. But on Ubuntu based PC, Chrome always download video clip to HDD instead playback one.
I dont know is it Linux distribution related problem but both installations use Chrome ver 38.
How can I change/setup to have MP4 files always be playback instead downloaded ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Google Chrome or Chromium on Ubuntu, as a matter of interest? Either way the issue may be that MP4 support has not been enabled.

To enable it you need to install the support for mp4 codec:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg
```

The reason for this is that some codecs are not fully open source, because they may be subject to patents for example, and hence they can't be included in a fully open source release.

See some discussion and references:

- https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/675
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra

Comment: Yes I use both Chrome and Chromium

Comment: does not work for me. I installed  both chromium-codecs-ffmpeg nad chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra but chromium still can't play mp4 (H.264) video. I added a note to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/991758

Comment: @djb Are you able to share an example video which will not play?

Comment: It turns out that chrome fails to play the videos when they are served from a SharePoint server (on our intranet). If I download the videos, I can Ctrl-O Open them in Chrome and view them. Same if I move them to a web server instead of a document folder in SharePoint. (Note that Firefox can view the files in the SharePoint folder)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by emailing not direct link to particular video clip but by email link to WEB page containing HTMLv5 code with "video" statement. It is more flexible because it works in any environment and in any browser compatible with HTMLv5.