# Playing 360 videos in Chromium and Mozilla nightly WebVR versions

Tags: html, webgl, mp4, chromium, webvr

I'm trying to integrate 360 videos in WebGL, using the HTML5 video player and a flat video it does work, but when I use this video by example :
http://video.airpano.com/Video-Porto/portu_fin3_ir2048_5mbs.mp4

all I get is a black screen.

I use the chromium version 44.0.2383.0 for WebVR (http://blog.tojicode.com/2014/07/bringing-vr-to-chrome.html).

Does anyone experimented this problem before, or managed to play 360 videos ? thank you for your help !

## EDIT

Here's the function I use to stream a videotexture :

```
that.loadVideoTexture = function(){
    // create the video element
    this.video = document.createElement("video");
    this.video.src = "http://video.airpano.com/Video-Porto/portu_fin3_ir2048_5mbs.mp4";
    this.video.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    this.video.crossorigin = "anonymous";
    this.video.load(); // must call after setting/changing source               

    this.videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(this.video);
    this.videoTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    this.videoTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

    this.mesh.material.materials[1] = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: this.videoTexture, color:"white", side:THREE.DoubleSide } );
}
```

But apparently it would be coming from the non support of .mp4 by Chrome, so I guess the code isn't involved in this problem.

Comment: When you use that video to do what? Playing it via the html `video` tag ? Trying to use it as video texture? How about some code, a fiddle, are you using plain webgl or a library, any errors in the console? If I tell you that my webvr video player implementation works how does this help you and potential future readers?

Comment: *"apparently it would be coming from the non support of .mp4 by Chrome"* try to read more precisely, the answer states that Chom**ium** does not include codecs for h264, and this is *by default*, [you could install/build with these codecs included](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524325/chrome-does-not-play-mp4).

Comment: @LJᛃ Unfortunately this is not easy to do on Windows (and may no longer work in Linux either). It seems Chromium changed the way they integrate h264 so the only option is to compile from source. At this point you might as well wait for WebVR to appear in Chrome proper. http://chromium.woolyss.com/#html5-audio-video

Comment: @brianpeiris Ah good to know, bad for the OP though :)

Answer (score 4):

Since Chromium is an open-source distribution, it does not include support for proprietary, licensed formats like MP4 (H.264). You'll either need to convert the video to WebM or use WebVR in Firefox Nightly instead.